# ggplot not drawing boxplots as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, tidyverse, boxplot

Consider the MWE below. I would like to generate boxplots with these ideas in mind:

1. `Food` on the y-axix ordered according to `Amot` for `Home`, while `Amt` (1:40) on x-axis
2. show mean points overlaying the boxes
3. boxplots of `Food` to be ordered based on median of `Home` *Site* from `dfsummary` data
4. text annotations of `N` of observations (to be taken from `dfsummary` data)

**MWE**

```
df <- data.frame(
  Site = sample(rep(c("Home", "Office"), size = 884)),
  Food = sample(rep(c("Banana","Apple","Egg","Berry","Tomato","Potato","Bean","Pea","Nuts","Onion","Carrot","Cabbage","Eggplant"), size=884)),
  Amt = sample(seq(1, 40, by = 0.25), size = 884, replace = TRUE)
)
random <- sample(seq(1, 884, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE) # to randomly introduce 100 NAs to Amt vector
df$Amt[random] <- NA
```

**Summary code**

```
dfsummary <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Food, Site) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Median = round(median(Amt, na.rm=TRUE), digits=2), N = sum(!is.na(Amt))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**ggplot code**

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Amt, Food)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(facets = . ~ Site)
```

**Graph**

[image]

I was expecting to see boxplots here.

**Adding annotation**

```
p2 <- p1 + geom_text(aes(y = 42, Food, label = paste("n=", N)), data = dfsummary, size = 3, nudge_x = 0.1) +
  facet_grid(facets = . ~ Site)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work either.

**Note**

- tidyverse version is 1.3.0
- R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12) -- "Dark and Stormy Night"

Comment: There is no boxplot because there is one point at each. So for home tomatoes there is one point only. If you would like to see boxplot given values for home/office then you will have to remove facet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine in the current development version of ggplot2, to be released in January 2020.

```r
# If your ggplot2 version is <= 3.2.1, do:
# remotes::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Site = sample(rep(c("Home", "Office"), size = 884)),
  Food = sample(rep(c("Banana","Apple","Egg","Berry","Tomato","Potato","Bean","Pea","Nuts","Onion","Carrot","Cabbage","Eggplant"), size=884)),
  Amt = sample(seq(1, 40, by = 0.25), size = 884, replace = TRUE)
)
random <- sample(seq(1, 884, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE) # to randomly introduce 100 NAs to Amt vector
df$Amt[random] <- NA

ggplot(df, aes(Amt, Food)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(facets = . ~ Site)
#> Warning: Removed 98 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

With annotations:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Site = sample(rep(c("Home", "Office"), size = 884)),
  Food = sample(rep(c("Banana","Apple","Egg","Berry","Tomato","Potato","Bean","Pea","Nuts","Onion","Carrot","Cabbage","Eggplant"), size=884)),
  Amt = sample(seq(1, 40, by = 0.25), size = 884, replace = TRUE)
)
random <- sample(seq(1, 884, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE) # to randomly introduce 100 NAs to Amt vector
df$Amt[random] <- NA

dfsummary <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Food, Site) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Median = round(median(Amt, na.rm=TRUE), digits=2), N = sum(!is.na(Amt))) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(df, aes(Amt, Food)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = 42, Food, label = paste("n=", N)),
    data = dfsummary,
    size = 3, nudge_x = 0.1
  ) +
  facet_grid(facets = . ~ Site)
#> Warning: Removed 95 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To work out the problem, you may want to generate a scatter plot, first:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Amt, Food)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(facets = . ~ Site)
p1
```

[image]

As you can see it is impossible to generate a boxplot. 
However, if you switch `x` and `y`

```
ggplot(df, aes(Food, Amt)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(facets = . ~ Site)
```

You get: 
[image]

Comment: how about ordering the labels of `Food` according to the median of `dfsummary`? How to do that in this graph?

Comment: The code does actually work, but you'll need the current development version of ggplot2.